# Cocoa: NextKeyView - Tab Order

Tags: cocoa

in my cocoa application I want to change the tab order of the controls so I can switch from a textfield to a button. I did connect the nextKeyView property of the textfield with the button but it seems to have no effect at all.

I already activated the appropriate system settings for Keyboard so I can tab to all controls now. It works fine but not in the order I set as nextKeyView.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a screenshot of the window in the running application.

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by @sach solved this for me.

I created a new storyboard project, and added 3 text fields. I set a custom order by linking them together with nextKeyView in Interface Builder, but this had no effect at runtime. This is the simplest test case that I could come up with to replicate your (and my) problem.

To solve it using @sach's answer, create a new outlet and connect it to one of the `NSTextField`s:

```
@IBOutlet var firstTextField: NSTextField!
```

In the ViewController, I then added:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    // Must execute this after the window is connected
    self.view.window!.initialFirstResponder = nameField
}
```

Re-run and the text fields cycle properly according to the order set using the nextKeyView links

Comment: Awesome! This worked. I set the `nextKeyView` for each `NSTextField` and then set the `initialFirstResponder` of the window to the first text field, and tab order works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect your window's `initialFirstResponder` outlet to at least 1 field. Some controls like NSTabView have one more initialResponder. So if you have anything inside tabview you need to connect them also.
**Overall logic is you need to connect all initialresponde to atleast 1 field**

Comment: Hi will it be depend on OSX version.. because tab order working by default in 10.9.2 OSX but not working in 10.8.5 OSX.. any help please.

Comment: OK, but how do you do that? If I control-click on the window and drag from the palette's "initialFirstResponder" circle, I can only target things in the same scene (ie. the window's scene), not from the View Controller scene...? (Setting it in viewDidLoad does not work.)